# ng-bind-html html with css does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```
<ion-item ng-bind-html="renderHtml(word[key])">

</ion-item>
```

Where word[key] is

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {padding: 1px 10px 1px 20px;list-style-type: upper-roman;}
```

I have a much more complex structure with css. The CSS works on cordova and react but since i am porting function to ng, the css do not work. Please Advise or point what i am missing here.

Comment: can you create a plnkr? http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing the angular XSS security in play (see http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$sce/unsafe).

There are 2 ways to fix this:

1. If the html is user created/influenced in some way, you will need to include the `$sanitize` module. Refer to the link above.
2. If the html is from you only, mark it as trusted HTML using `$sce.trustAsHtml`. Something like:

```js
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('myctrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.renderHtml = function(html) {
    return html;
  };
  $scope.word = $sce.trustAsHtml('\
<ul>\
  <li>item 1</li>\
  <li> item 2 </li>\
  <li>item 3</li>\
</ul>');
});
```

```css
ul {padding: 1px 10px 1px 20px;list-style-type: upper-roman;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
  <ion-item ng-bind-html="word"></ion-item>
</div>
```

Comment: I am already using your 2. method. The issue is <ul> css is not loading. I have checked by adding <ul style="list-style-type: upper-roman;">. Which actually worked, but is an ugly solution. The html elements such as <p><ol> are in separate CSS.

Comment: @moeen-ud-Din I've updated my snippet. As you can see, the CSS works perfectly fine.